# Change process name in Linux

Tags: c, linux, process

I'm on Linux and I am forking/execing a new process out of my C spawn application. Is it possible to also change the naming of these new child processes?

I want to be able to identify the process being started in case something goes wrong and I need to kill it manually. Currently they all have the same name.

Comment: processes don't have names

Comment: Thanks Neil. When I look into the Systems Monitor, it does actually show me a name which is what I was referring to. What method would I use instead then?

Comment: I suspect that is the file name of the executable that created the process - you can't change that.

Comment: You can, I just don't know if it's a good idea. :)

Comment: @Amadan You can (unportably) change the representation.

Comment: @nbt:  if processes don't have names then what changes if you call `prctl(PR_SET_NAME, ..)` or change `argv[0]`? (look at `ps axo comm,args`) Some environments provide [`setproctitle(3)` function](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setproctitle&sektion=3). Its [multi-platform implementation is possible](http://doxygen.postgresql.org/ps__status_8c_source.html)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think this should work, to illustrate the principle...

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  argv[0][0] = 65;
  sleep(10);
}
```

will change the name, and put an "A" instead of the first letter. CtrlZ to pause, then run `ps` to see the name changed. I have no clue, but it seems somewhat dangerous, since some things might depend on `argv[0]`.

Also, I tried replacing the pointer itself to another string; no cigar. So this would only work with `strcpy` and strings shorter or equal than the original name.

There might or might not be a better way for this. I don't know.

EDIT: nonliteral solution: If you're forking, you know the child's PID (`getpid()` in the child, result of `fork()` in the parent). Just output it somewhere where you can read it, and kill the child by PID.

another nonliteral solution: make softlinks to the executable with another name (`ln -s a.out kill_this_a.out`), then when you exec, exec the link. The name will be the link's name.

Comment: Thanks Amadan, +1 this is such a smart idea. Have you tried it before. I mean, could it possibly cause any problems?

Comment: @Frank: This is supported, and if you observe your system, you'll find a few programs that do it. You're constrained by the size of the existing arguments: you can just overwrite individual characters, not resize the buffer or use a different one.

Comment: There's ugly hacks to reuse the environment variables for extra space, see e.g [here](http://koders.com/c/fidE817FBB097E080657B0A6977E5F4C9612BC1E923.aspx?s=setproctitle.c) . With recent kernels you can also do `prctl(PR_SET_NAME, (unsigned long) "My Process", 0, 0, 0);` - but not all utilities use that name as the default display name (top does, ps does not) and it has a limit of 16 characters.

Comment: @Frank: Some other options added - not quite answers to your question, but probably answers to your problem.

Comment: The include should be of `unistd.h`, not `stdio.h`.

Comment: If "no cigar" means "not working", I guess it's because `argv` points to a process-reserved memory segment that is used by utilities like `ps`, which is why you can't just change `argv[0]`.

Answer (score 5):

One of the comments mentions `prctl`, but this really deserves its own answer, because setting `argv[0]` will not work in all cases (it does nothing on my system).

There are at least two library calls to set the name of a thread in Linux, both limited to 15 characters plus the terminating `NUL` byte:

1. glibc-specific: `pthread_setname_np(...)` where the `np` stands for "non-portable", but this might be present on some other OSes: https://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_setname_np
2. Linux-specific: `prctl(PR_SET_NAME...)` which is also non-portable: https://linux.die.net/man/2/prctl

---

## Example

Here's a test of the different methods (with no error handling):

```c
// gcc pstest.c -o pstest -O2 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -Wno-unused -Wno-unused-result -std=gnu99 -pthread -D_GNU_SOURCE 
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/prctl.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    puts("Initial ps output:");
    system("ps | grep pstest");

    puts("\npthread_setname_np");
    pthread_setname_np(pthread_self(), "setname");
    system("ps | grep setname");

    puts("\nprctl");
    prctl(PR_SET_NAME, (unsigned long)"prctl", 0, 0, 0);
    system("ps | grep prctl");

    puts("\nargv[0]");
    argv[0] = "argv0";
    system("ps | grep argv0");

    return 0;
}
```

Notice the lack of output after `argv[0]`:

```sh
./pstest
Initial ps output:
17169 pts/0    00:00:00 pstest

pthread_setname_np
17169 pts/0    00:00:00 setname

prctl
17169 pts/0    00:00:00 prctl

argv[0]
```

## In the wild

[Here's an example in production code](https://github.com/nitrogenlogic/nlutils/blob/bc546d9539d5efd6b4ede417760101db44ee1cec/src/thread.c#L15-L40) (as always, be sure to take note of the license when looking at code on GitHub)

## See also

See also these questions and answers:

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167490/how-can-a-process-appear-to-have-different-name-in-ps-output
- [Using prctl PR_SET_NAME to set name for process or thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453048/using-prctl-pr-set-name-to-set-name-for-process-or-thread)

Comment: The argv[0] part is wrong: you have to overwrite the memory directly, not just change the pointer: `strcpy(argv[0], "argv[0]");`. That's why the Chromium version has this ugly hack that adds up all the space of the different arguments in argv to allow a longer name than what the program was originally called with. It makes use of the fact that in Linux, all of argv is in contiguous memory (i.e. argv[1] == argv[0] + strlen(argv[0]) + 1)

Answer (score 5):

According to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082189/change-process-name-in-linux#comment7046519_6082228), `prctl(PR_SET_NAME)` only affects the "short name" of a thread. It has the same effect as writing into `/proc/self/comm`.

To change the "long name" (`/proc/self/cmdline` which is actually used by `htop` and `ps u`) you need some ugly hack (which is mentioned in that comment but the link is dead). An example of this kind of hack can be found in Chromium source code: https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:content/common/set_process_title_linux.cc

Answer (score 1):

This is a non-portable hack:

```
/*
 * Sets process title, truncating if there is not enough space, 
 * rather than causing memory corruption.
 */
void set_title_np(int argc, char **argv, const char *title) {
    // calculate available size
    size_t space = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
        size_t length = strlen(argv[i]);
        space += length + 1; // because of terminating zero 
    }
    memset(argv[0], '\0', space); // wipe existing args
    strncpy(argv[0], title, space - 1); // -1: leave null termination, if title bigger than space
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The below code sample would change the name of the process to "Testing".

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <string.h>

    int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char* temp = (char*) malloc (20);
    strcpy(temp, "Testing");
    temp[7] = 0;
    printf("Argv[0] --> %s\n", argv[0]);
    argv[0] = temp;
    printf("Argv[0] --> %s\n", argv[0]);    
    return 0;
    }
```

The output of above program is:

./a.out

Argv[0] --> ./a.out

Argv[0] --> Testing

The argv[0] contains the name of the process.

Comment: Unfortunately this won't change the output in `ps`.

Comment: You can't change where `argv[0]` points.  You have to change the memory that `argv[0]` points to.  Obviously that's problematic because it may not be big enough, hence the other more complex solutions.