# Using prctl PR_SET_NAME to set name for process or thread?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, process

I am trying to use `prctl( PR_SET_NAME, "procname", 0, 0, 0)` to set name for a process, when I am reading the Linux Manual about the PR_SET_NAME, looks like it set the name for thread if I understand it correctly.

Can `prctl` be used to set name for process? How to set name for process?

Comment: This is how they do it in Nginx: http://lxr.nginx.org/source/src/os/unix/ngx_setproctitle.c

Comment: That URL has changed format slightly: http://lxr.nginx.org/source/xref/nginx/src/os/unix/ngx_setproctitle.c

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you may use `PR_SET_NAME` in the first argument and the name as the second argument to set the name of the calling thread(or process). `prctl` returns `0` on success. Remember, it depends where you call this `prctl`. If you call it inside your process, it will change the name of that process and all of its belonging threads. If you call it inside a specific thread, it will change only the name of that thread.

Example:

```
int s;
s = prctl(PR_SET_NAME,"myProcess\0",NULL,NULL,NULL); // name: myProcess
```

Now, if you are running your process in Linux, type:

```
top
```

or

```
ps
```

To see the name attached to your process id.

Comment: Wrong: doing this will indeed change the process name but you won't see any difference in PS nor TOP commands. That's because to accomplish what you want you must change argv[0] which is the one reflected by those two comands.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a reason you added an extra `\0` to the parameter `"myProcess\0"`?  C strings are already terminated with `\0`

Comment: @Zibri. ps -o comm will show a difference. So will htop if you also add the COMM column. Difference is between /proc/<pid>/comm and /proc/<pid>/cmdline

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
const char *newName = "newname";
char *baseName;

// find application base name to correct
char *appName = const_cast<char *>(argv[0]);
if (((baseName = strrchr(appName, '/')) != NULL ||
   (baseName = strrchr(appName, '\\')) != NULL) && baseName[1]) {
   appName = baseName + 1;
}

// Important! set new application name inside existing memory block.
// we want to avoid argv[0] = newName; because we don't know
// how cmd line buffer will be released during application shutdown phase
// Note: new process name has equal or shorter length than current argv[0]
size_t appNameLen;
if ((appNameLen = strlen(appName)) != 0) {
    strncpy(appName, newName, appNameLen);
    appName[appNameLen] = 0;
}

// set new current thread name
if (prctl(PR_SET_NAME, reinterpret_cast<unsigned long>(const_cast<char *>(newName)), NULL, NULL, NULL)) {
    Log::error("prctl(PR_SET_NAME, \"%s\") error - %s", newName, strerror(errno));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the process name you can use as you did prctl but that will show up only in /proc/pid/status (and programs using it).
ps and top look elsewhere and to change the process name shown in ps and top, you must just change argv[0].

so just assigning it as argv[0]="newprocessname";  wil do.

Comment: Can you add an example and share what distribution and Kernel version you are using?  Changing `argv[0]` did not work for me, but `pthread_setname_np` and `prctl` did work.

Comment: you have to do both, as I said.  ubuntu 16-17-18 any kernel