# Ubuntu (linux in general) How to change name of background process?

Tags: php, linux, process

When we run the "top" command from command line we can see the processes and under the COMMAND column we see a generic name.
For e,g if I run a php process in the background like

```
/usr/bin/php /path/to/myscript.php &
```

I see just `php` listed under the COMMAND column when I run `top`.

Is there a way to change the name of the background process when I run it?

*This question is PHP specific.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using prctl PR\_SET\_NAME to set name for process or thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30453048/using-prctl-pr-set-name-to-set-name-for-process-or-thread)

Comment: Looks strongly like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info). **Why** do you need to change the name of the background process? There are very few reasons to do this. Most PHP (or other) programs don't need to do that. If you have some related sysadmin issue, please tell.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch just for readability. When you start 25 background processes and do a top or ps-uax instead of all of them showing as php. if they show as php1, php2, php3.. it lends a nice readability touch to it.

Comment: I believe that is the wrong reason. You can use `ps auxw`

Answer (score -2):

A process don't really have a name, it has a pid (of type `pid_t` which is some integer, the result of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) or related system call). Read [credentials(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html).

And the displayed `php` name is the right one, it is the one given to [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) as the first argument of index 0 and it is the program name. The kernel don't run directly your PHP script, it is running the `php` interpreter which takes *as input* your script (so the actual program which is run is `php`). And your shell command is *explicitly* giving `/usr/bin/php` as the program name. You could use [strace(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/strace.1.html) to check that.

Your shell is displaying (via `jobs -l`) the [background processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Background_process). So you could write your own shell to display them differently.

Perhaps you could write in C some wrapper ELF executable which does the appropriate [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html).

**I'm not sure it is worth the trouble**. See also [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) to understand how applications (like your shell, or  `ps`, or `top`) are querying the kernel about processes (using `/proc/` file-system).

As commented by [melopmane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene), look also into [prctl(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/prctl.2.html) and `PR_SET_NAME`
(I never used that). I did however use [pthread_setname_np(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_setname_np.3.html) which concerns a *thread*.

<sup>(still, I don't think it is worth the trouble in your case; what is wrong with having a PHP process called `php`?)</sup>

See also [setproctitle](http://php.net/setproctitle), or write some PHP [extension](http://php.net/manual/en/internals2.structure.php) in C to do that...

**But you should not care!** and I even think that changing that way the name of your process is *confusing* to the sysadmin. He wants to know that it is some PHP thing. So even if you could abuse your sysadmin, you should not want to.

BTW, you could check (using [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)...) with a command like `cat /proc/1234/maps` (replace 1234 with the actual pid of your process) that the PHP interpreter is an important part of your [virtual address space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_address_space) (so there is no reason to "hide" `php` as you want to), and you could find your specific `php` process (if you have many of them) using also [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html).

Comment: What about `prctl` with `PR_SET_NAME`?